# Can we integrate activiti to an excisting spring(java) application

Tags: activiti

I am having a spring(java) application running on tomcat server, i want a work flow process of creating a ticket and maintain ticket status as it progresses and give permission to write(update) data of the ticket depending on the status of the ticket and the role of the user(i will give roles like admin and user thats it).

Can i achieve it with Activiti ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can. In the words of Joram Barrez (Activiti Architect), Activiti is really just a jar. Well, he understated it a little, it's a jar and a database. But either way, it is really easy to integrate Activiti into any existing Java app. Check out the following [link](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#springintegration) from the users guide to show you how to setup the Process Engine factory and associated beans in your spring configuration.

Comment: Can we apply rules to the states like if it is in some state a user cannot change any data(eg. in telephone interview a user cannot change data of his details)

Comment: Sure, that's all part of the BPMN model.

Comment: but i didnt see any rules applying while creating bpmn model can you refer to any example where such rules are applied